# ATI Triple Head / Eyefinty: valid replacement for 2 cards?

Tags: amd-radeon

I'm currently using two ATI 4850 cards to work with three 24" 1920 x 1280 monitors. Because of the heat and power consumption, I'm considering switching to one of the new 5000 ATI cards with support for 3 monitors with just a single card, so I will only need to use (and cool..) one card instead of two. My question: will the behavior under Windows be the same? E.g., will Windows still see three independent displays or will the ATI driver somehow emulate one big monitor for Windows with a large resolution or some other nonsense? Is there any difference with such a setup compared to two 'old' cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will still see three monitors, like your current setup and each can have it's own resolution.

Comment: You can also SET EyeFinity to emulate one big monitor (a 'display group').  It's really the best of both worlds.